# How when Button pressed twice the color should change using NSUSerDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I am new to XCode. I used with `NSUserDefaults` even though it is not coming what i required means If i click one time on that button it should change the colour to *green* and if i press it again it should change the colour to black.

Here my Code is -

```
- (IBAction)subscribeButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if (count == 0) {
        [_subscribeButtonObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        greenStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"green"];
        NSUserDefaults *greendefults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [greendefults setValue:greenStr forKey:@"greencolor"];
        [greendefults synchronize];
        ///
        count++;
    } else if(count == 1){
        [_subscribeButtonObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        blackStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"black"];
        NSUserDefaults *blackDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [blackDefaults setValue:blackStr forKey:@"blackcolor"];
        [blackDefaults synchronize];
        //count = 0;
    }
}
```

In `ViewWillAppear` I wrote the code like this -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //count = 0;
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"greencolor"]) {
        NSLog(@"change the button to green color %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"greencolor"]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"change the button to blackcolor ");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are not even using NSUserDefault properly. This is not the way. NO

Comment: @iworld Use BOOL member and switch it accordingly

Comment: Did you configure button action in IB? If not add it first. And Why you are using NSUSerDefaults here? You can simply use one BOOL variable for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna do it the NSUserDefault way. Setting control states is a nice way though. but It  will set a unwanted overlay background to the button if `UIControlStateSelected` is `YES`. :

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *color=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (count == 0) {
        [self.btnOutlet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [color setValue:@"green" forKey:@"color"];

    }else if(count == 1){
        [self.btnOutlet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [color setValue:@"blue" forKey:@"color"];

    }
    count = !count;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    count = 0;

    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"color"] isEqualToString:@"green"]){ // been used
        [self.btnOutlet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }else if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"color"] isEqualToString:@"blue"]){
        [self.btnOutlet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }else{ // first time
        [self.btnOutlet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of `NSUserDefaults` to implement this. Its simple to handle with `UIButton`'s control states,

- `UIControlStateNormal`
- `UIControlStateSelected`

For example,

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (button.selected) { // If selected will change the color into Red
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [button setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [button setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

And, keeep in mind you can change your button's state initially like setting this,

```
[myButton setSelected:YES];
```

Assign, this code in your `viewDidLoad`

Cheers!!